# How can I search and get the directory of a DLL file in python

Tags: python, search, dll, operating-system, ctypes

Let's say if I have a `dll` file called `banana.dll`, and I have a module called `banana.py` which will use `ctypes` to load `banana.dll`, and they are stored in the same directory, for exmaple `c:\Python27\lib` in Windows.

Now I create a new python file called `testing.py` in other directory (for example `c:\user\desktop` ) which will import the `banana.py` module. But since the current working directory is the directory where `testing.py` is stored. So I need to manually change the directory to `c:\Python27\lib` by hardcoding it.

But is there a smarter way that I can search the path where `banana.dll` is stored?

Answer (score 3):

If you have pywin32 installed:

```
import _win32sysloader
mod = 'banana'
path_to_mod = _win32sysloader.GetModuleFilename(mod) or _win32sysloader.LoadModule(mod)
```

Or

```
import win32api
mod = 'banana'
path_to_mod = win32api.GetModuleFileName(win32api.LoadLibrary(mod))
```

If you don't have pywin32, you can use ctypes to access win32 api:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HANDLE, LPWSTR, DWORD

GetModuleFileName = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetModuleFileNameW
GetModuleFileName.argtypes = HANDLE, LPWSTR, DWORD
GetModuleFileName.restype = DWORD

mod = 'banana'
MAX_PATH = 260
dll = ctypes.CDLL(mod) or ctypes.WINDLL(mod)
buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(MAX_PATH)
GetModuleFileName(dll._handle, buf, MAX_PATH)
path_to_mod = buf.value
```

Don't forget to handle WindowsError and other possible exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import banana
import os.path

module_dirname = os.path.dirname(banana.__file__)
```

Comment: What you are doing actually is to get the dirname of `banana.py`, is it? Will this still work if `banana.py` and `banana.dll` are stored in different directory?