# Get absolute path of shared library in Python

Tags: python, c, dll

Let's say I wanted to use libc in Python. This can be easily done by

```
from ctypes import CDLL
from ctypes.util import find_library

libc_path = find_library('c')
libc = CDLL(libc_path)
```

Now, I know I could use ldconfig to get libc's abspath, but is there a way to acquire it from the CDLL object? Is there something that can be done with its `_handle`?

*Update*: Ok.

```
libdl = find_library('dl')
RTLD_DI_LINKMAP = 2
//libdl.dlinfo(libc._handle, RTLD_DI_LINKMAP, ???)
```

I need to redefine the `link_map` struct then?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A handle in this context is basically a reference to the memory mapped library file.

However there are existing ways to achieve what what you want with the help of OS functions.

**windows:**
Windows provides an API for this purpose called `GetModuleFileName`. Some example of usage is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007896/how-can-i-search-and-get-the-directory-of-a-dll-file-in-python).

**linux:**
There is existing a `dlinfo` function for this purpose, see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlinfo.3.html).

---

I played around with ctypes and here is my solution for linux based Systems. I have zero knowledge of ctypes so far, if there are any suggestions for improvement I appreciate them.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

#linkmap structure, we only need the second entry
class LINKMAP(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("l_addr", c_void_p),
        ("l_name", c_char_p)
    ]

libc = CDLL(find_library('c'))
libdl = CDLL(find_library('dl'))

dlinfo = libdl.dlinfo
dlinfo.argtypes  = c_void_p, c_int, c_void_p
dlinfo.restype = c_int

#gets typecasted later, I dont know how to create a ctypes struct pointer instance
lmptr = c_void_p()

#2 equals RTLD_DI_LINKMAP, pass pointer by reference
dlinfo(libc._handle, 2, byref(lmptr))

#typecast to a linkmap pointer and retrieve the name.
abspath = cast(lmptr, POINTER(LINKMAP)).contents.l_name

print(abspath)
```

Comment: To be more straightforward: lmptr = POINTER(LINKMAP)(); ...; abspath = lmptr.contents.l_name;